# Can you target an illusion from Major Image with Magic Missile?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion, targeting

## Can you target an illusion from Major Image with Magic Missile?

The spell *[major image](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Major%20Image#content)* has been used to create the illusion of a creature.  A character does not know it is an image and attempts to cast *[magic missile](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Magic%20Missile#h-Magic%20Missile)* at it.

What happens when the character attempts to cast *magic missile* targeting the illusion?

Comment: Major illusion to mean as if from the spell *major image* or a colloquial sense of any illusion of prominence?

Comment: @DavidCoffron We'll go with major image.